# Using rand() to generate numbers around a variable?(C++)

Tags: c++, random

I am making a small text-based game in c++ called "House Evolution" for fun. The game consists of 'searching under the couch cushions' to gain credits. When you search, the game is supposed to generate a random number anywhere from creditRate-5 to creditRate+5. How would I go about doing this using the rand() function, no matter what number creditRate is? Here is example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int creditRate = 30; // Just for example.
    int credits;
    int searching;

    while (1) {
        // Yes, I know, infinite loop...
        std::cout << "Credits: " << credits << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Type any key to search for credits: " << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Searching...\n";
        usleep(10000000); // Wait 10 seconds

        searching = rand(?????????); // Searching should be creditRate-5 to creditRate+5

        std::cout << "You found " << searching<< " credits\n";
        credits += searching;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/ ... in the first section of the documentation it answers this exact question. `A typical way to generate trivial pseudo-random numbers in a determined range using rand is to use the modulo of the returned value by the range span and add the initial value of the range`. By the way, nobody on Stack Overflow is ever made at beginners just because they're beginners. We get mad when askers don't do research and expect to waste our time instead of using their own.

Comment: Could you expand on that?

Comment: obligatory: [rand() considered harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)

Comment: Which part should I expand on? [Here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/2150749) is an expansion of my last couple of sentences. I would quote part of it, but really the whole answer is worth reading.

Comment: @KeeganJack in regards to what Jashaszun said, I typed "c++ random number" into google and literally the first auto-complete suggestion was "c++ random number between" to which there were countless links, all of which would have answered your question. Now if you tried one, got a compiler error or unexpected behavior, then you should post here with your code to get help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I would go about it is using rand % 11, to get a range of 11 numbers and then adding it to credit rate -5 to cover the range from creditrate-5 to creditrate+5.
So:

```
searching = rand() % 11 + creditRate - 5;
```

Comment: Of course, unless RAND_MAX is a multiple of 11 then you get biased results using this method. Plus it's not as readable as using `uniform_int_distribution` where the range is stated directly: `uniform_int_distribution<>(creditRate - 5, creditRate + 5)` is clearer than `% 11 + creditRate - 5`

Comment: Yeah you are correct on the biased front however that is roughly 1 in 3000 against a few of them. Importing <random> and trying to explain that and mersenne twisters can be counter productive at the very early levels of beginning programming. I was going for a chunk of code I could readily explain fully to help their current case.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend trying to explain it, just providing the magic incantations. Similar to how there's no need to explain anything about `cout` to beginners, you only need to show them the bit they might want to change: how to give different things to `cout`/how to select different ranges to generate.

Answer (score 2):

Try: 
`searching = rand() % 11 + creditRate-5;` That's because your range is 11 (remember, there are 11 numbers from -5 to 5, for example) and the lower limit is creditRate-5.

Comment: Pretty much it however this range is from 0-9 so it will never hit creditRate+5. Negligible issue, right idea.

Comment: @Jashaszum: Thanks for the fix.Yes, I forgot to close the interval.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `<random>` header instead of `rand()`, because `<random>` provides facilities to generate these distributions correctly instead of making you do it yourself.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    int creditRate = 30; // Just for example.
    // Searching should be creditRate-5 to creditRate+5
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> random_credit_amount(creditRate - 5, creditRate + 5);

    int credits = 0;

    // arrange a source of randomness
    std::random_device r;
    std::seed_seq seed{r(),r(),r(),r(),r(),r()};
    std::mt19937 pRNG(seed);

    while (true) {
        // Yes, I know, infinite loop...
        std::cout << "Credits: " << credits << '\n';
        std::cout << "Type any key to search for credits: " << '\n';
        std::cout << "Searching...\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10)); // Wait 10 seconds

        int searching = random_credit_amount(pRNG);

        std::cout << "You found " << searching<< " credits\n";
        credits += searching;
    }
}
```

`<random>` even provides more advanced options than the typical uniform distribution. For example, instead of having every values from `creditRate - 5` to `creditRate + 5` be equally likely, you could have values closer to creditRate be more likely than values further away, using a 'normal' (a.k.a. 'bell curve') distribution:

```
// credits found should be near creditRate
std::normal_distribution<> random_credit_amount(creditRate, 5);
```

and then in the loop:

```
    int searching = std::round(random_credit_amount(eng));
```

(You don't have to change the code in the loop at all, but it skews the distribution a bit. Performing proper rounding avoids the skew.)

---

Notice another change I made, replacing the non-standard `usleep` with the standard `this_thread::sleep_for`. Notice that this code makes the comment entirely redundant:

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10)); // Wait 10 seconds
```

And one can just as easily ask for sleep durations of microseconds or hours

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::hours(2));
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(50));
```